# find value in array according to the row and column number

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have two matrix A and B,the first row of matrix A(1,:)=[1 2] refer to the number of row and column matrix B(1,2)=21,now I want to do this work for another rows of matrix A without loops?

```
A=[1 2;2 3;1 3;3 3];
B=[1 21 34;45 65 87;4 55 66];
for i=1:4
d(i,:)=B(A(i,1),A(i,2))
end
d =[21; 87;34;66]
```

Comment: None of the above solutions work when size(A,1) is too large. The reason behind is that all of the solutions above imply creating a matrix of dimensions size(A,1) x size(A,1). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60477249/get-matrix-values-at-millions-of-index-pairs-efficiently-matlab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to `sub2ind` is

```
d = B(A(:,1)+ (A(:,2)-1)*size(B,1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [**`sub2ind`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to get linear indices of the required values of `B` and then use these indices to retrieve those values.

```
d = B(sub2ind(size(B), A(:,1), A(:,2)));
```

```
>> d

d =

    21
    87
    34
    66
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the following code must be work for you:

```
A=[1 2;2 3;1 3;3 3];
B=[1 21 34;45 65 87;4 55 66];
d=diag(B(A(:,1),A(:,2)))
```